# Why is the output from subprocess in wrong order?

Tags: java, linux, process, stream

I have a Java program that executes `sh` in interactive mode as a subprocess. The input is copied from `System.in` and output is copied to `System.out`. Everything works fine except that when running commands such as `pwd` in this interactive shell the output appears in a wrong order, for example:

```
$ pwd
$ /home/viz/workspace
```

instead of

```
$ pwd
/home/viz/workspace
$
```

The difference is that in the first case the prompt `$` is printed before the output from `pwd`.

Any ideas why does it happen and how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class StreamCopier implements Runnable {
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;

    public StreamCopier(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int n;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                out.flush();
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -i +m");
        Thread outThread = new Thread(new StreamCopier(
                process.getInputStream(), System.out));
        outThread.start();
        Thread errThread = new Thread(new StreamCopier(
                process.getErrorStream(), System.err));
        errThread.start();
        Thread inThread = new Thread(new StreamCopier(
                System.in, process.getOutputStream()));
        inThread.start();
        process.waitFor();
        outThread.join();
        errThread.join();
        inThread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run a different shell?

Comment: @dacwe: I could only make `sh` work so far. Tried `bash` but it is stopped when trying to do IO. Probably it needs some other options (`+m` doesn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because standard error and standard output go to different threads which print the read data asynchronously. It might work, if you redirect `2>&1`, but I'm not sure it will work with `Runtime.exec` (may cause "file not found - 2>&1"). So you can make a shell script which calls `sh` and redirects its output, and call that script using `Runtime.exec`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sh -i +m 2>&1
```

and

```
Runtime.exec("customsh");
```

Comment: But both `$` and `/home/viz/workspace` should be outputted on standard output? (so no race there..)

Comment: @dacwe No. Try from the command-line `sh 1>temp.log` and then type `pwd`. You will see the command-line prompt but not pwd output, it will go to `temp.log`.

Comment: Nice! Then there is vitaut solution!