# Groovy process output not in the correct order

Tags: java, maven, groovy, process, io

I have gone through the following:

- [Why does output appear in wrong order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959548/why-does-output-appear-in-wrong-order)
- [Why is the output from subprocess in wrong order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216626/why-is-the-output-from-subprocess-in-wrong-order)

I have tried the solutions mentioned at:

- https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/FIO07-J.+Do+not+let+external+processes+block+on+IO+buffers
- https://leo3418.github.io/2021/06/20/java-processbuilder-stdout.html

The groovy script does not print output in the correct order. Here is the implementation:

```
final String command = "cmd /c mvn -e --no-transfer-progress clean compile -Psome-profile"    
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split())                                    
processBuilder = processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)                                              
final Process proc = processBuilder.start()                                                            
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

The order of the output is incorrect:

```
[WARNING] D:\checkstyle\src\main\java\com\puppycrawl\tools\checkstyle\checks\imports\ImportControlLoader.java:[185,78] [argument] incompatible argument for parameter parent of FileImportControl.
  found   : @Initialized @Nullable PkgImportControl
[WARNING]
  required: @Initialized @NonNull PkgImportControl
```

Whereas it should be:

```
[WARNING] D:\checkstyle\src\main\java\com\puppycrawl\tools\checkstyle\checks\imports\ImportControlLoader.java:[185,78] [argument] incompatible argument for parameter parent of FileImportControl.
  found   : @Initialized @Nullable PkgImportControl
  required: @Initialized @NonNull PkgImportControl
[WARNING]................
```

Groovy version:

```
Groovy Version: 2.5.18 JVM: 11.0.16.1 Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc. OS: Windows 11
```

**Note:** This particular maven command takes a long to execute and dumps out the logs at the end (not continuously) which is a contributing factor to the above issue, any help will be really appreciated.

Update:

Upgraded groovy version to:

```
Groovy Version: 4.0.5 JVM: 11.0.16.1 Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc. OS: Windows 11
```

Still isn't working correctly.

Comment: Any suggestions? An alternative approach will also do the job.

Comment: You can buffer the output and then dump it when the process finishes to reduce the chance of interleaved output.

Answer (score 0):

try to redirect stderr to stdout using cmd:

```
String [] command = [
    "cmd", "/c", 
    "mvn -e --no-transfer-progress clean compile -Psome-profile 2>&1"
]
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command)
Process proc = processBuilder.start()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```